# Fetching data using onChange jquery ajax issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

here in my code i am trying to fetch and display the data after selecting a option from the dropdown using onChange, fetching data from a PHP file and via ajax displaying it in textarea in same **select.php** file but unfortunately it is not working out for me am quit confused were i made a mistake, please help me out on this.

**select.php**

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#channel").change(function(){
    $.post("ajax.php", { channel: $(this).val() })
     .success(function(data) {

             $(".result").html(data);
         });
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
    <select class="chosen-select form-control" id = 'channel' name="ProductCategoryID"  value="<?php echo set_value('ProductCategoryID'); ?>" required>
        <option>Select Item code</option>
        <?php 
            foreach($itemlist as $row)
            { 
                echo '<option value="1234">'.$row->ItemCode.'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 form-group result"></div>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','***');
define('PASS','***');
define('DB','***');

$response = array();

$conn = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

//get value from page

$channel = $_POST['channel'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM gst_itemmaster where ItemCode = '$channel' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$msg = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $msg = $msg. '<textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="Description"></textarea>'.$row['ItemDescription'].'</textarea>';
}

echo $msg;
```

Comment: You can add console.log(data);   in   success function of ajax call and add error_reporting(E_ALL); in your ajax.php to see any server errors or notices in browser console.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $msg = $msg. '<textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="Description"></textarea>'.$row['ItemDescription'].'</textarea>';
}
```

Try using:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $msg = $msg. '<textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="Description"></textarea>'.$row['ItemDescription'].'</textarea>';
}
```

May be it would help

Comment: Thanks bud for reply..ya i missed out on that thanks but i am facing same issue even after that rectification..!

Comment: SELECT * FROM gst_itemmaster where ItemCode ='$channel' 

I am not sure what your query is but I think correct syntax should be like above..What error you get anyways.?

Comment: Please see the updated code but still its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to initiate **$msg** first and use mysqli module.

```
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','***');
define('PASS','***');
define('DB','***');

$response = array();

$conn = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

//get value from page

$channel = $_POST['channel'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM gst_itemmaster where ItemCode =$channel";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$msg = '';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $msg = $msg. '<textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="Description"></textarea>'.$row['ItemDescription'].'</textarea>';
}

echo $msg;
```

**UPDATE**
Update your post request with:

```
$.post("ajax.php",
    { channel: $(this).val() },
    function(data) {
        $(".result").html(data);
    }
);
```

OR

```
$.post("ajax.php",
    { channel: $(this).val() },
    successCallback
);

function successCallback(data){
    //process data..
}
```

see [https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: As @vishi mentioned in his comment, try to enclose the $channel variable in single qoute in the query (e.g. "SELECT * FROM gst_itemmaster where ItemCode = '$channel'").

Comment: please see the updated code is it fine now though its not working out

Answer (score 0):

replace,
$.post("ajax.php", { channel: $(this).val() })
with
$.post("ajax.php", { 'channel': $(this).val() })

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("ajax.php", { channel: $(this).val() },function(data) {
    $(".result").html(data);
});
```

Please remove .success(function(data){ }) from the code and it will work :)